# The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0

Tags: c#

Here's a part of the code..

//HERE'S FOR INSERT

```
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();

command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblUsersAccount (Username,[Password],Firstname,     MiddleName, Lastname,Birthday,ContactNo,DateCreated,DateModified) values (@Username,@Password,@Firstname,@MiddleName,@Lastname,@Birthday,@ContactNo,@DateCreated,@DateModified)";

command.Parameters.Add("@Username", OleDbType.Char).Value = tbUsername.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("@Password", OleDbType.Char).Value = tbPassword.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("@Firstname", OleDbType.Char).Value = tbFirstname.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("@MiddleName", OleDbType.Char).Value = tbMiddleName.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("@Lastname", OleDbType.Char).Value = tbLastname.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("@Birthday", OleDbType.Date).Value =DateTime.Parse(tbBirthday.Text);
command.Parameters.Add("@ContactNo", OleDbType.Char).Value = tbContactNo.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("@DateCreated", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Now;
command.Parameters.Add("@DateModified", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Now;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

//HERE'S FOR UPDATE

```
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();

command.CommandText = "UPDATE tblUsersAccount SET Password = ?, Firstname = ?, MiddleName = ?, Lastname = ?, Birthday = ?, ContactNo = ? WHERE Username = ?";

connect.ConnectionString = connectionString;
connect.Open();
command.Connection = connect;

command.Parameters.Add("@Username", OleDbType.Char).Value = tbUsername.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("@Password", OleDbType.Char).Value = tbPassword.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("@Firstname", OleDbType.Char).Value = tbFirstname.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("@MiddleName", OleDbType.Char).Value = tbMiddleName.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("@Lastname", OleDbType.Char).Value = tbLastname.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("@Birthday", OleDbType.Date).Value =DateTime.Parse(tbBirthday.Text);
command.Parameters.Add("@ContactNo", OleDbType.Char).Value = tbContactNo.Text;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

problem #1: having an error in the update part. the error says, "The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0." which is on the birthday part. even if date is in correct format like 09/08/11. which works in insert part.

problem #2: when i tried to remove the birthday part to see if there's some errors other than on problem #1, here's the error "Syntax error in update statement."

sorry.. im just new to programming. and thanks for the help. God bless.

Comment: I have no idea whether you're talking about the 8th of September 2011, or the 9th of August, 2011, or the 11th of August 2009, or 8th September 1911, or quite a few other possibilities. If I run `DateTime.Parse(@"09/08/11")` on my machine I get 2009-08-11 00:00:00 but that won't be true for all set-ups. Your code should be set to enforce whatever rule you use, but I can't advise how to do that, because again I don't know what that rule is.

Comment: .. found out the problem. It's the column name "Password".. might be a reserved word. I enclosed it in bracket [Password], and works! :D

Thank you so much to those who answered my question. :)

Comment: Worthy doing a more explicit `Parse` version so it works on other systems (either explicitly tell it to use `mm/dd/yy` or explicitly tell both it and the code that produces that result to make use of the culture for the system).

Answer (score 1):

The update fails because the parameters are not in the correct order.
The OleDb ADO provider requires that you add the parameter to the collection in the exact order in which they appear on the sql update string

Try to move the UserName parameter at the end

```
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(); 

command.CommandText = "UPDATE tblUsersAccount SET [Password] = ?, Firstname = ?, " + 
                      "MiddleName = ?, Lastname = ?, Birthday = ?, ContactNo = ? " + 
                      "WHERE Username = ?"; 

connect.ConnectionString = connectionString; 
connect.Open(); 
command.Connection = connect; 

command.Parameters.Add("@Password", OleDbType.Char).Value = tbPassword.Text; 
command.Parameters.Add("@Firstname", OleDbType.Char).Value = tbFirstname.Text; 
command.Parameters.Add("@MiddleName", OleDbType.Char).Value = tbMiddleName.Text; 
command.Parameters.Add("@Lastname", OleDbType.Char).Value = tbLastname.Text; 
command.Parameters.Add("@Birthday", OleDbType.Date).Value =DateTime.Parse(tbBirthday.Text); 
command.Parameters.Add("@ContactNo", OleDbType.Char).Value = tbContactNo.Text; 
command.Parameters.Add("@Username", OleDbType.Char).Value = tbUsername.Text; 
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Now the order of the parameters is the same in which they appear in the update string and the date values are correctly understood.

Comment: It is the Password field? I see that in the Insert is inside square brackets. It is a reserved word in your database ([Probably Access?](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321266))

Answer (score 1):

Date problem might be, while ADO is converting your date-time object into string using current locale. I'd rathe tried

```
DateTime.Parse(tbBirthday.Text).Date
```

as was specified by user `leppie`.

For the problem #2, take a look to the SQL expression you have for instert, and for update. Inside Insert you are using `@columnName`, and in update you are using `?` sign. Try to use full name for the parameter, as in Insert SQL: `@columnName`

Comment: i tried to use same as what i used in insert but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in the date (which it seems so):

`DateTime.Parse(tbBirthday.Text).Date`

or

`DateTime.Today`

in the other cases.

Answer (score 0):

try with  Date property of DateTime

```
 command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblUsersAccount (Username,[Password],Firstname,     MiddleName, Lastname,Birthday,ContactNo,DateCreated,DateModified) values (@Username,@Password,@Firstname,@MiddleName,@Lastname,@Birthday,@ContactNo,@DateCreated,@DateModified)";

command.Parameters.Add("@Username", OleDbType.Char).Value = tbUsername.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("@Password", OleDbType.Char).Value = tbPassword.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("@Firstname", OleDbType.Char).Value = tbFirstname.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("@MiddleName", OleDbType.Char).Value = tbMiddleName.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("@Lastname", OleDbType.Char).Value = tbLastname.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("@Birthday", OleDbType.Date).Value =DateTime.Parse(tbBirthday.Text).Date;//<---
command.Parameters.Add("@ContactNo", OleDbType.Char).Value = tbContactNo.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("@DateCreated", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Now.Date; //<---
command.Parameters.Add("@DateModified", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Now.Date;//<---
```